# Using WGET to Get All of the .mov Files from Diggnation

Tags: video, download, script, wget

I'm trying to download every single episode of Diggnation using WGET to grab the small QuickTime movies. It would be too tiring to go through every single page to download them. Here's what I'm thinking:

```
 wget -r -l 1 -A mov http://revision3.com/diggnation/
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Anyone have a better idea on how to get all the eps? Here's an example URL:

http://revision3.com/diggnation/2005-07-01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wrote a C# WPF app to go get them all for me, right now it is about 10 episodes in. Let me know if you want the source!